# How do GLM deal with grouping variables for post-hoc tests?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

I am analyzing my dataset with a binomial GLM with the following model:

```r
> expressed/notexpressed ~ treatment + gene + timepoint + 
          timepoint:treatment + gene:treatment + gene:timepoint + 
          (1|exp) + (1|cell)
```

Here is the associated R code:

```r
glm_2 <- glmer(cbind(expressed, notexpressed) ~ treatment + gene + 
    timepoint + timepoint:treatment gene:treatment + gene:timepoint + 
    (1|exp) + (1|cell), raw_data, family = binomial, 
    control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", 
    optCtrl = list(maxfun = 10000)))
```

And then I am performing the post-hoc test as follows, in order to compare the 3 timepoints:

```r
emmeans(glm_2, pairwise ~ timepoint|treatment*gene, type = "response")
```

I am happy with my model and the results, but I'm puzzled by a particular result, as illustrated on the following figure:

[image]

For Gene Z, there is obviously a drastic change for the "treatment" condition (blue) between Day 4 and Day7/Day10, which leads to high statistical significance.

However, for the "control" condition (red), there is barely any difference between the timepoints, but I still get very high statistical significance between Day4-Day7 and Day4-Day10. The Day7-Day10 difference is not statistically significant, which is suspiciously similar to what is observed in the "treatment" condition.

So, it seems to me that the "treatment" values are somehow affecting the results for the "control" condition. It do not understand why, as I specify in the post-hoc test to take into account the "treatment", and get separate results for each condition:

```r
treatment = Control, gene = GeneZ:
 contrast         odds.ratio       SE  df null z.ratio p.value
 D10 / D4    0.04383  0.02059 Inf    1  -6.656  <.0001
 D10 / D7    0.57506  0.24661 Inf    1  -1.290  0.4007
 D4 / D7    13.12129  5.47774 Inf    1   6.166  <.0001

treatment = Treatment, gene = GeneZ:
 contrast         odds.ratio       SE  df null z.ratio p.value
 D10 / D4    0.00931  0.00482 Inf    1  -9.036  <.0001
 D10 / D7    0.48158  0.23898 Inf    1  -1.472  0.3042
 D4 / D7    51.72804 23.37762 Inf    1   8.731  <.0001
```

However, I do not know how GLM deal with this sort of grouping variable "separation" ("treatment" in this case), so those results might be actually expected with this kind of analysis?

I would thus like to know how GLM deal with this sort of case, in order to better understand my results. Any pointer is appreciated!

Comment: Where did you get your mean estimates from as well as the standard errors (or confidence intervals?) that are shown in  your graph? Can you provide the emmeans code as well as the results that were used for generating your graph? I think this has nothing to do with GLMs in general but is more related to what happended when you used your model together with emmeans (unless you used a mixed effects model; then information from clusters specified in the random effect can be borrowed to adjust the mean estimates).

Comment: There is almost complete separation in the Gene Z / Treatment / Day 10 group (if I read the graph correctly, there is a single non-zero observation in that group). The model doesn't include a three-way product term (only two-way interactions), so yes your intuition is correct that "the "treatment" values are somehow affecting the results for the "control" condition."

Comment: @Stefan On the graph, the big dots & bars represent the average and the SEM, using % values, and the transparent dots represent each measurment. For the binomial model I didn't use % but the raw counts express/not expressed (e.g. 12/24 for the model vs 33% for the graph).

The code for the model and post-hoc test with emmeans are here, what else would be helpful to add? The more complete output of emmeans?

In my model there are two random effects: (1|exp) + (1|cell) so I guess this is a mixed model indeed. Could you elaborate on how that could affect the results?

Comment: @dipetkov thanks for the explanation, you read the graph correctly. Indeed when I change the model and add a three-way interaction between "treatment," timepoint" and "gene", this solves this nonsensical result.

Comment: You cannot use the raw data percentages and error bars to display on a graph and then add signficance tests which you got from your model. Depending on what predictors you add the mean values estimated by the model can change (as well as the standard errors) and will not be comparable to the raw values anymore. There might also be problems with complete separation as @dipetkov pointed out. Re-run you emmeans call but leave out `pairwise`, that will give you the probabilites plus errors. These are the model means which should go in the graph.

Comment: Then in the next step you can get the pairwise comparisons and use those with the estimated mean values. Also if you haven't looked at it yet, under "Vignettes" you can find a ton of useful information for emmean, incl. FAQs https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html

Comment: @Stefan I appreciate the advice very much. It would make indeed make more sense to present results this way.

Comment: Happy it helped :) Good luck with your analysis!